# custom DateTime model binder not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I am using Asp.Net MVC 4 and this is my custom model binder:

```
public class DateTimeModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
    {
        private string _customFormat;

        public DateTimeModelBinder(string customFormat)
        {
            _customFormat = customFormat;
        }

        public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
            if(value != null)
                return DateTime.ParseExact(value.AttemptedValue, _customFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and this is my Web API method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Register(RegistrationUser registrationUser)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new StringContent("User is created") };
            }
            else
            {
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
                {
                    Content =
                        new ObjectContent<IEnumerable<string>>(ModelState.Values.SelectMany(f => f.Errors.Select(s => s.ErrorMessage)),
                        new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())
                };
            }
        }
```

registrationUser has `BirthDate` of type `DateTime?`. When I submit a valid value `23/05/2014` it won't accept and model binder is never executed.

I have this in global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime), new DateTimeModelBinder("dd/mm/yyyy"));
            ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime?), new DateTimeModelBinder("dd/mm/yyyy"));

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();

        }
```

This is my RegistrationUser POCO:

```
 public class RegistrationUser
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email address is required")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [NullableRequired(ErrorMessage = "Gender is required")]
        public short? GenderID { get; set; }

        [NullableRequired(ErrorMessage = "Birth Date is required")]
        public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }

        [NullableRequired(ErrorMessage = "Profile For is required")]
        public short? ProfileForID { get; set; }
    }
```

What am I missing?

PS: If I add an attribute

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(DateTimeModelBinder))]
    public class RegistrationUser
```

it would work fine but this is tedious and time consuming plus error prone. I don't want to add this to each model. I want that `DateTimeModelBinder` should be used always for `DateTime` and `DateTime?`

**Update:**

Looks like I needed to use JSON.Net's converter feature:

```
public class DateTimeConverter : DateTimeConverterBase
    {
         private string _dateFormat;

         public DateTimeConverter(string dateFormat)
        {
            _dateFormat = dateFormat;
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            try
            {
                if (reader.Value != null && reader.Value.ToString().Trim() != string.Empty)
                    return DateTime.ParseExact(reader.Value.ToString(), _dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            catch
            {                
            }
            return null;
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            writer.WriteValue(((DateTime)value).ToString(_dateFormat));
        }
    }
```

and then I had to add this in WebApiConfig:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(
             new DateTimeConverter("dd/mm/yyyy"));
```

and it works!

Comment: would be great to provide your solution as an answer, not as UPD or something else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are writing an MVC model binder and trying to use it in a Web API controller. The two systems are similar, but not compatible with each other in terms of the types being used.

The types in the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace are all MVC, whereas the types in the `System.Web.Http` namespaces are all Web API.

The registration of MVC and Web API model binders is also similar in some ways, and different in others. For example, you can use the `[ModelBinder(typeof(XyzModelBinder))]` attribute on the type in question to declare a model binder in both systems. But registration of a global model binder is different.

In MVC you register a global model binder like so:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Xyz), new XyzModelBinder(...));
```

In Web API it is like so:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Add(typeof(ModelBinderProvider), new XyzModelBinderProvider());
```

With regard to MVC vs. Web API, please check that you're not mixing up those types - many types have the same or similar name except that they're in different namespaces.

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand. Could you please post me a working sample? How does model binder work in web api? There is no DefaultModelBinder in System.Web.Http

Comment: @Jack there's no `DefaultModelBinder` but given that you're implementing everything custom anyway you can implement the `System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.IModelBinder` interface directly because it has essentially the same shape.

Comment: @Jack I made some edits to my response to clarify some more and give some more examples.

Comment: Hmmm, looks like I moved in the wrong direction. All I wanted is to convert date time into specific format. I've wasted lot of time in wrong direction. Please check my edit after 2 mins and let me know what you think.

Comment: @Jack ah, if all you need is to decide how JSON dates should be formatted, your new code could very well be all you need.